# Runtime scope and `main` symbol is different inside or outside a function

Tags: python, scope

I am reading the [code for testing in TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/googletest.py), called by [the tests in the MNIST official model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist_test.py). The file has these lines without scope modifiers:

```py
from unittest import *
unittest_main = main
```

and this function, also without scope modifiers:

```py
def g_main(argv):
  """Delegate to unittest.main after redefining testLoader."""
    ...
    return unittest_main(argv=argv)
```

And the `main` function calls `g_main`:

```py
def main(argv=None):  # pylint: disable=function-redefined
  def main_wrapper():
    args = argv
    if args is None:
      args = sys.argv
    return app.run(main=g_main, argv=args)
  benchmark.benchmarks_main(true_main=main_wrapper)
```

This seemed circular: `main` calls `g_main`, which calls `main`. So I added some prints below the definition of `unittest_main = main` and inside the `g_main` function:

```py
unittest_main = main
#Added by me:
print(unittest_main)
print(main)
for local_var in list(locals()):
    if not local_var.startswith('__'): print(local_var)


# pylint: disable=invalid-name
# pylint: disable=undefined-variable
def g_main(argv):
  """Delegate to unittest.main after redefining testLoader."""
    # Added by me:
    for local_var in list(locals()):
      if not local_var.startswith('__'): print(local_var)

    print(unittest_main)
    print(main)
    return unittest_main(argv=argv)
```

Running `python models/official/mnist/mnist_test.py`, I got:

```
absolute_import
division
print_function
atexit
...
unittest_main
<class 'unittest.main.TestProgram'>
<class 'unittest.main.TestProgram'>
argv
<class 'unittest.main.TestProgram'>
<function main at 0x11e55ff28>
```

Therefore the `main` symbol changes definition when called outside or inside the function `g_main`, and the runtime scope is different as well. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two *different* `main`s floating around (well, `main` gets redefined mid-file).

```
from unittest import *
unittest_main = main
```

simply assigns `unittest.main` to the name `unittest_main`.

Later they *redefine* `main` to be as such:

```
def main(argv=None):  # pylint: disable=function-redefined
  def main_wrapper():
    args = argv
    if args is None:
      args = sys.argv
    return app.run(main=g_main, argv=args)
  benchmark.benchmarks_main(true_main=main_wrapper)
```

which means that the name `main` now refers to the above function instead of `unittest.main`. `unittest_main` still is bound to `unittest.main`, however.

Your prints are telling you this as well. The first time you printed `main` (*before* redefinition), it printed `<class 'unittest.main.TestProgram'>`. The next time, it output `<function main at 0x11e55ff28>` (since it's now no longer `unittest.main` and has been redefined as above).

`g_main` only has references to the name `unittest_main` which, again, is `unittest.main`.

I think it would have been better if they would just do `import unittest`, reference `unittest.main` (instead of renaming it to `unittest_main`) and be done with it. Then there wouldn't be a need to redefine the name `main`. Furthermore, they wouldn't be polluting their current namespace with everything from `unittest` (you don't want to `import *` for many reasons, here's one of them). They're violating their own style guide and PEP8...and making this it way more confusing than it has to be.

Wild guess: someone lazily did `from unittest import *` when tensorflow was a wee baby and just didn't realize the consequences, and it snowballed from there.

HTH.

Comment: Clear and very helpful, thanks! I wondered if `main` had a different meaning or scope, but your explanation would apply to any symbol, they just called it `main`. This is a nice example where reusing variables is a bad idea.

Comment: Would you like to submit a pull request to TensorFlow with those changes, or should i?

Comment: I don't use github very often: so go for it